# How to get total sum in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple table and I want to get the total per table. Please see the demo in fiddle.

```
var total = 0;
$("table").each(function(i){
    total += +$('.a', this).text() || 0;
    console.log( 'total: '+total );
    $("#subtotal", this).text( total );
    //console.log( '-'+$('.a', this).text() );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/juandela/6r1g30dx/2/

Comment: `$("table tr")` not `$('table')`

Comment: Thanks for answering. the first table is correct but in the second table it also add up the total in the first table

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I changed id to class. Still getting the same result.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `var total=0` inside the table loop so it resets for each table

Then you need to loop over each cell to get individual cell's text.

The problem with getting all `$('.a', this).text()` is it concatenates all elements text into one string which is why you see numbers like `"1357"` as total in first table

Finally you can't repeat ID's in page so change subtotal to a class

```js
$("table").each(function(i) {
  var total = 0;
  $('.a', this).each(function() {
    total += +$(this).text() || 0;
  });
  $(".subtotal", this).text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a">11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm .. I totally forgot about resetting the total :)

Comment: @charlietfl WOW! This solve me question. Thank you so much.

Comment: and @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you

Comment: @charlietfl Am sorry I cant accept your answer because I have less than 15 reputations.

Comment: @Juan...don't worry about downvotes. In future though will help to include enough html in question so it is self contained